# Dynamic resize with MPlayer and PyGTK

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, mplayer

I've wrote a piece of code in python and pygtk for an embeded mplayer in a gui.
I assume I use GtkSocket and the slave mode of mplayer with the -wid option.

But I've got an issue, when the size of my GTK window is smaller than my stream, the stream appears to be cropped. And when the size of my window is bigger than my stream, the stream appear centred inside the widget which embed MPlayer. (a gtk.Frame but I've also try with a gtk.DrawingArea)
I would like to know how I can get my stream resize dynamically depending on the window's size.
I don't want to use Glade or any GUI builder.
Thanks in advance for any help, and please excuse my poor english.

Comment: Posting your code would most decidedly help. Please stop replying with answers, answers are for just that .. _answers_ to your question. Please read [our FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to connect to the `'size-allocate'` signal of whatever widget you embedded MPlayer in. Once you know the new size of the widget, say 200x300, send the commands

```
set_property width 300
set_property height 200
```

to MPlayer in slave mode.

(See http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt for a list of slave mode commands.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but if the get_property is okay, set_property doesn't exist, according to your link about mplayer slave mode.

Comment: Hi,
I've found some example of somebody did that but I don't understand how!
Here is his code: http://www.dinointeractive.com/?p=36
I just don't understand what am I missing!

Comment: set_property is about halfway down the page, between set_mouse_pos and speed_incr. Ctrl-F is your friend.

Comment: What don't you understand about the code? Could you be more specific?

Comment: For the set_property: look at the table a the end of the doc. There's no set_property for height and width. Only get.
I don't understand how this guy did to resize the stream, when I resize the window! I did nothing with mplayer in particular, so I guess he done it with pyGTK but I can't find how he procced =(
Thanks for your help =)

Comment: I would said "HE" did nothing in particular with mplayer.
Also, I've sent an email to him... but it seems that he doesn't or can"t answer to me. His blog was not update since last july so..

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell mplayer to zoom video according to window size. This can be done either in command line (-zoom) or in the configuration file (zoom = 1).